# A Quas/ Quarum Conflict

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

In North & Hillard Ex. 200; the following is to be translated into Latin: "He forgot all the wrongs which he had suffered, and by his arrival brought safety to the state which had treated him so unjustly."

Answer: "qui omnium iniuriarum quas passus erat oblitus adventu suo civibus qui sese tam iniuste usi erant salutem attulit."

Tried: "...omnium iniuriarum quarum (gen. pl.) passus erat..." giving "...of all of the injustices of which he had suffered..." instesd of the given "...of all of the injustices which/ that/ these ("quas" - acc. pl.) he had suffered...".

Is this permissible?

Was going to ask about species, "sese", but it`s well-covered in Wiktionary.

Comment: The genitive *omnium iniuriarum* is governed by *obliviscor,* which (always) takes the genitive. "Having forgotten all..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use the two deponent verbs ***patior*** suffer; and ***obliviscor*** forget; then you have to stick to the rules and put the object of *patior* into the accusative, and the object of *oblivisco*r into the genitive.

In the relative clause "which he had suffered," **which** is the object of *passus est* so it must be Accusative. But it takes number and gender from 'the things/ the injuries'  In the model answer 'injuries' give fem pl. In your example you seem to be edging towards 'those things.' neuter plural.

In the Participle phrase "Having forgotten all those injuries" *Oblitus* is going to be Nominative (the same case as the Subject of the main verb 'he brought') and *omnium injuriarum* is going to be Genitive as the object of *oblitus,* having forgotten.

If you prefer *cum* instead of the participle, *Cum oblitus est/sit omnium inj. ...* When he had forgotten/ Since he had forgotten...
If you want to keep two main clauses as in the original:  *Oblitus est omnium ... autem salutem attulit.* 'He forgot all ... but he brought safety.'

As for your second question on *qui... qui,*  [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DQ%3Aentry%20group%3D6%3Aentry%3Dqui1) **Qui II** C., D., E., F. may be helpful. That is: ***Qui*** used as a demonstrative; or to introduce qualitative or final clauses.